# HTML Parsing with Python (HTML vs. complete website)

Tags: python, html, parsing, urllib

I'm trying to parse html from a website that contains information about train tickets and there prices (source below), however I'm having an issue getting back all the html from the website when I use urllib to request the html.

What I need is the price per ticket which doesn't seem to appear when I used urllib to request the html. After doing some investigative work, I determined that if I save the webpage with chrome and select "HTML only", I don't get the price, however if I select "Complete WebPage," I do. Is there anyway to view the HTML that I get when I download the "Complete Webpage" and use that in python. Or is there a way to automate the downloading of the complete webpage and use the downloaded files to parse in python.

Thanks,
George

https://www.raileurope.com/en/us/point_to_point/ptp_results.htm?execution=e3s1&resultId=147840746&cobrand=public&saleCountry=us&resultId=147840746&cobrand=public&saleCountry=us&itemId=-1&fn=fsRequest&cobrand=public&c=USD&roundtrip=0&isAtocRequest=0&georequest=1&lang=en&route-type=0&from0=paris&to0=amsterdam&deptDate0=06%2F07%2F2017&time0=8&pass-question-radio=1&nCountries=&selCountry1=&selCountry2=&selCountry3=&selCountry4=&selCountry5=&familyId=&p=0&additionalTraveler0=adult&additionalTravelerAge0=&paxIds=&nA=1&nY=0&nC=0&nS=0

Comment: Are the desired tags being generated dynamically using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Use a module like `requests` to crawl to the desired website. This will mimic a user using a browser to view it. From there, you can use `beautifulsoup` or any other parser to get the needed info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
Since the website is rendered by JS, you will have to use a webdriver to simulate the "Click".
You will need a crawler instead of a simple scraper